# Correct use of public static const, error 1119

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a SpeachBubble class that is linked to a MovieClip:

```
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;

    public class SpeachBubble extends MovieClip {

        public static const SPEACH_POSITION_LEFT:String = 'speachPositionLeft';
        public static const SPEACH_POSITION_RIGHT:String = 'speachPositionRight';

        private var currentPosition = SPEACH_POSITION_LEFT;

    }
```

I also have a method called "Speak" which is attached to my characters, the method looks like this:

```
public function speak(text:String, position:String, displayTime:Number = 2500)
```

I would like to be able to call the speak method like this:

```
man.speak("I'm saying something!", SpeachBubble.SPEACH_POSITION_LEFT);
```

But I just get the error:

**1119: Access of possibly undefined property SPEACH_POSITION_LEFT through a reference with static type Class.**

**EDIT:** I've uploaded the full project [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?6o3b4n3wwgo7o55), I'm using CS6 but have saved as CS5 version in-case you haven't upgraded yet. It contains 1 fla file, and some classes, for the entry point see the first frame on the timeline.

Comment: I would like to add that, yes.. I've imported the class correctly

Comment: This works fine for me so chances are you have something else wrong. Like maybe package is incorrect.

Comment: Really? It (compiler) allowed this -> 'I'm saying something!' rather than "I'm saying something!"?

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela: No it didn't, just a mis-type when I posted the question. Thanks.

Comment: Could you share the entirety of the project code. There is a portion missing cause the way you are using public static constants works.

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite: Hi, I've edited the question with a link to the source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in your CS6 linkage settings.  Your not using the fully qualified namespace.

In your library, right click your 'Man' asset, and goto symbol properties.  In your class path, use **classes.intro.Man**   - you current just have it as 'Man', which would be the equivalent of having a Man.as file in the root of your project directory.

Make the subclass empty, as it is derived from your class file.  (though I believe it will ignore it anyway if it finds a class file with that namespace)

Do the same for your SpeachBubble